# How do I exclude database triggers from a DACPAC project created in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, dacpac, database-deployment

I have a database project in Visual Studio, and I need to exclude the database triggers from the generated DACPAC, because one of them is `LockdownTriggers` which prevents triggers from being altered - and that's causing issues with the other triggers; as soon as `LockdownTriggers` is deployed, it's automatically enabled. and then the rest of the deployment fails trying to alter other triggers that are now locked. Is there any way to prevent the database triggers from being deployed as part of the DACPAC? Or at least exclude `LockdownTriggers`, or prevent it from being enabled until the deployment is over?

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Searched around online some more and it looks like I need "Advanced Deployment Settings" (accessible via Project Properties > Debug > Advanced).

[image]