# How do I prevent database triggers from being deployed in Azure DevOps when I deploy a DACPAC as part of a release pipeline?

Tags: sql-server, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dacpac, database-deployment

So I figured out how to [disable the triggers from being part of a DACPAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933913/how-do-i-exclude-database-triggers-from-a-dacpac-project-created-in-visual-studi), but unfortunately that's just a user level setting in Visual Studio, so I can't save it to source control and deploy the solution with those changes.

There's got to be some way to filter out the triggers from the DACPAC in the definition of the deployment pipeline task. But I have no idea where to start; all I see are some text fields and none of them are even generic "command line options" fields...

Comment: You could try to add the [argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#properties-specific-to-the-publish-action) /p:DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers=True, It specifies whether Data Definition Language (DDL) triggers are disabled at the beginning of the publish process and re-enabled at the end of the publish action.

Comment: How do I specify that in the context of an Azure DevOps release pipeline task? I'm looking at the task definition and there's no field for command line arguments...

Comment: Oh, I had some sort of composite "task group" thing, I had to dig into the actual task to add that option. Still, it didn't work; I get the same errors...